# Grouping data based on a condition

Tags: sql-server

Effectively I want to be able to group data based on a condition.

I have:

[image: Sample data]

I want the data grouped using value effectively as a breakpoint.

[image]

I know how to do this with a cursor and some relatively simple logic.  However I'd rather use a set based solution.

Comment: What's your SQL Server release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) & [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx) function

```
declare @T TABLE
(name nvarchar(55),surname nvarchar(55), dates datetime, value decimal(18,2))

insert into @T values ('David','Example','2015-08-24 15:00:00.000',7.7)
insert into @T values ('David','Example','2015-09-10 15:00:00.000',7.7)
insert into @T values ('David','Example','2015-09-10 16:00:00.000',7.7)
insert into @T values ('David','Example','2015-09-10 16:00:00.000',7.8)
insert into @T values ('David','Example','2015-09-20 20:00:00.000',7.7)
insert into @T values ('David','Example','2015-09-20 20:00:00.000',7.7)

;with cte as
(SELECT name,surname, [Dates],[Value],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cast(dates as date) ORDER BY value desc)  AS RN
FROM @t)

select name,surname, [Dates],[Value] from cte
where RN = 1
```

Comment: Right idea, wrong answer.

Comment: Based on the sample data provided, you will not get the answer demonstrated in the question

Comment: @MarkSinkinson i tried to fix it i hope it is correct :)

Comment: Nicely corrected!